# Customize ZSH prompt across all themes

Tags: zsh, zshrc

**tl;dr: How can I modify my host (`%m` in prompt) such that it will be modified regardless of theme?**

On my work computer, I cannot change my hostname. I have edited a (oh-my-)zsh theme to replace the host (`%m`) when i'm on `myridiculoushostname.evil.corp` with something shorter. I'd like to try out more (oh-my-)zsh themes (e.g. by setting my theme to `random`), but I'd like to somehow modify just the host component of the prompt in all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky Answer: do all of your magic in your root `.zshrc`, and do it on the shell variable `HOST`. For example, adding `HOST="test"` to your `.zshrc` will make `%m` and `%M` both read `test`. The reason I called this hacky is `HOST` is a general shell variable, and its possible other applications and scripts will check it's value.

'Right' Answer: Set your own prompt in your root `.zshrc`, and handle the hostname magic the exact same way you handle it right now. This has the downside that the prompt for each theme isn't shown, but AFAIK there's no way to directly modify what %m evals to.

Answer so Scary I almost Didn't write it: At the end of your `zshrc`, use awk to do a string replace on the `PROMPT` variable. You can simply map `%m` to a string of your choosing, effectively doing the prompt substitution for zsh. This will work no matter what theme you use, but it just seems obtuse.

e.g.: `PROMPT=$(echo $PROMPT | sed 's/%m/test123/')`

Comment: I actually think I like the last one best since I'm worried other work tools may be expecting $HOST to have the current value. and I want to see the different proposals in the various themes for how prompts could look

Comment: @Michael yeah, I think it is the only way to fully get the behavior you describe, but just remember to map both `%m` and `%M`. I think I was being a little harsh with my 'ohh soo scary'

Comment: Why run several processes including sed when zsh offers simple and elegant parameter substitution with search and replace? `PROMPT="${PROMPT//\%m/test123}"`